# Как грамотно заменить explode?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида `a/b/c/d/e`.

Нужно запихнуть ее в массив таким способом:

```
$a=explode('/', 'a/b/c/d/e');
```

Разделитель может быть любым.

Как сделать так, чтобы если перед разделителем стоит `\` , то разделитель не учитывается?

Т.е. если стоит символ экранирования, то чтобы такой вариант не срабатывал `\/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут скорее подойдет [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php), чем explode().

```
$str = 'a/b/c/d/e\/f/g/h\/i';
$arr = preg_split('~(?<!\\\)/~',$str);
```

В итоге получим:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e\/f
    [5] => g
    [6] => h\/i
)
```

Comment: А что обозначает `?<!` ?

Comment: @fjghkjg, Негативный просмотр назад с отрицанием.

    /(?<!a)b/ - найдет "b", если перед ним не будет "a"

Comment: а как то можно по другому записать это выражение например так?

`/[^\\\]\//`

или я ошибся?

Comment: @fjghkjg, вы же и сами проверить можете )) Ошиблись.

Comment: @Deonis, не силен в регулярных выражениях)

Правильно ли я понял, что без `?<!` не обойтись?

Comment: @fjghkjg, какую-то альтернативу, скорее всего, найти можно, только не уверен, что это будет лучше:

    $str = 'a/b/c/d/e\/f/g/h\/i';
    $arr = preg_match_all('#([a-z]\\\/[a-z])|([a-z])#',$str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]); // результат тот же, НО только для данного примера

Comment: @Deonis, а как сделать вариант с `//`

Не правильно работает

`$str = 'a/b/c/d/e//f/g/h//i';`

`$arr = preg_split('~(?<!/)/~',$str);`


Ответ должен получаться таким

`a`

`b`

`c`

`d`

`e//f`

`g`

`h//i`