# Preg_split головоломка -  кто сможет решить?

Tags: php

На основе предыдущего вопроса

[Как грамотно заменить explode в моем случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360425/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-explode-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5)

Как сделать вариант с `//` ?

Неправильно работает:

```
$str = 'a/b/c/d/e//f/g/h//i';
$arr = preg_split('~(?<!/)/~',$str);
```

Ответ должен получаться таким

```
a
b
c
d
e//f
g
h//i
```

Немного подумав, я написал такой код:

```
$str = 'a/b/c/d/e//f/g/h//i';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/',$str);
```

Ответ:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e//f
    [5] => g
    [6] => h//i
)
```

На первый взгляд, он работает правильно, но если символов много `////` , то уже нет:

```
$str = 'a/b/c/d/e////f/g/h//i';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/',$str);
```

Ответ должен получиться таким:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => //
    [6] => f
    [7] => g
    [8] => h//i
)
```

Как исправить?
@Deonis

Comment: Что-то вроде:  

     /(?<!\/)\/(?!\/(?:\/\/)*))/

Неясно, как нужно разделить:  

    e///f
    e/////f

Comment: Для ваших вариантов, [можно попробовать так][1]:

    $arr = preg_split('#(?<![a-z]\/)\/(?=[a-z]|\/{3})#',$str);

Но соглашусь с @ReinRaus - что делать, если подряд будет нечетное количество слэшей или их будет парунадцать штук?

   [1]:http://ideone.com/GLUR4J